# Updating Dynamic Columns Issue

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to update values in table emp. Which column to update is dynamic.

```
public void updateEmployees(List<String> columnDb, List<String> columnValues)
{
   var data = ctx.tblEmployee.Where(e => e.Id == empId).Select(e => e).SingleOrDefault();
   ....

   data.columnDb = columnValues; // Pseudo       

   ctx.tblEmployee.Add(data);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

How to update columns which are passed dynamically as a parameter?

Comment: Why don't you update all columns, even columns in which data hasn't changed? just pass the the already existing db values where you don't really need to update.

Comment: `List columnDb` don't contain all Columns so i cannot update all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the power of Reflection.

Just iterate through properties of your object and set the value for the properties that you have in your list.

First, let's build a dictionary with property names and values from your parameters to make the value access easier:

```
var values = columnDb.Zip(columnValues,
        (name, value) => new { Name = name, Value = value })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Now, iterate through properties and set values:

```
var data = ctx.tblEmployee.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == empId);
foreach(PropertyInfo property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // Check if property should be updated
    if(values.ContainsKey(property.Name))
    {
        var value = values[property.Name];
        // Change the type of the value to the type of the property
        object converted = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
        // Set the property value
        property.SetValue(data,values[property.Name]);
    }
}
```

Of course, the code above assumes that there is a conversion between `string` and the type of the properties of your data object.